# ReactJS : Props indefinidos en componentes

Tags: reactjs, props, componentes

He estado trabajando en un pequeño proyecto en donde obtengo datos de un backend personal. La cosa es que cuando obtengo los datos los seteo en un estado. Y luego los paso a un componente,
la primera  vez renderizan bien, pero cuando me muevo de una página a otra el estado lo pierdo y se vuelve indefinido.(ejemplo  estoy en el perfil me muevo a la configuración y vuelvo al perfil aparece todo undefined)

A continuación les dejo una muestra de mi código:

```
const Profile = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [user, setUser]=useState({})
  useEffect(async ()=>{
   const token = localStorage.getItem("token")
 
    try {
      const {data} = await axios.get("api/user/data")
      setUser(data.user)
     
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      Alert("error", "Por favor, inicia sesión nuevamente")
      setTimeout(()=>{
        router.push("/signIn")
      },3000)
      
    }
  },[])
  //getProfileUser
 
  return (
    <Layout className={classes.root}>
      <ToastContainer/>
        <Intro  description={user.description} hobbies ={user.hobbies}/>
    </Layout>
    
  );
};
export default Profile;
```

y acá es donde quisiera mostrar los datos como la descripción y los hobbies, intenté colocarlos en estados pero pasaba igual.

```
const Intro = (Props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const hobbies = Props.hobbies
  return (
    <Card className={classes.container}>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography className={classes.title} color='textPrimary' gutterBottom>
          Sobre mi
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant='body1' align='justify' children={Props.description} />

        <Typography>
          <span style={{ fontSize: '30px' }}>&#127918;</span> Mis hobbies:
        </Typography>
        {
          hobbies.map((hobbies, index)=>(
            <ul>
            <li key={index}>
              {hobbies}
            </li>
            </ul>
          ))
        }
        
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

Gracias por leerme (: espero qque estén teniendo una linda noche. Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los hooks `useEffect` son sincrónicos, esto para prevenir situaciones [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). Debes poner la función `async` dentro del `scope` de `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    // Aquí espera
    const {data} = await axios.get("api/user/data")
    setUser(data.user)
    // ...
  }
  fetchData();
}, [dependencia]); // O [] si el efecto no necesita props or state
```

Además, supongo que fue un typo de tu lado, pero este `alert` va en minúsculas:

```
alert("error", "Por favor, inicia sesión nuevamente")
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

[fetch hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-do-data-fetching-with-hooks)

Comment: muchas gracias! me ayudo mucho :D!